# nsurlrequest settings for POST

Tags: iphone, ios

I am setting up a request to my server, I have been helped out with a few suggestions but I am wanting some clarification on a part of code.

in the second line of code, what are the **setValue:** and **forHTTPHeaderField:** values used for? I'm thinking forHTTPHeaderField: sets the mime type... but im not sure what setValue is for or how it effects my request.

```
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postBodyData];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the NSMutableURLRequest [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the method description and HTTP [documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) at **14.17 Content-Type** section for the header information.

More C-T details at the [section 7.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html)

> **Content-Type specifies the media type of the underlying data**. Content-Encoding may be used to indicate any additional content codings applied to the data, usually for the purpose of data compression, that are a property of the requested resource. There is no default encoding.
>
> **Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body.** If
>   and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

Comment: thanks very much for the links.. I checked out the apple documents, they give the most unhelpful (to me anyway) description **Parameters
value
The new value for the header field. Any existing value for the field is replaced by the new value.
field
The name of the header field to set. In keeping with the HTTP RFC, HTTP header field names are case-insensitive.
**

Comment: @C.Johns see the added info, it should make Content-Type header usage more clear. As for the setValue: forHTTPHeaderField: function, the second parameter is responsible for ANY header name (case-insenssetive in writing) and the first is the value for that header. Yes, the headers should have values and the header names are the keys (like a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML request consists of a request header and body.

In your example you define that the body of this request contains form data.

If for example you want to submit a json structure as your request body, the content type of the request is to be set as "application/json".

Comment: yep, I understand that, so in which case **forHTTPHeaderField** would have my jason MIME type.. not sure what it is. But what would be my setValue? say if i was sending straight data.. with my own format...

Comment: the value for the "application/json" mimetype example could be: {"name":"some name"}

Answer (score 0):

In the case of content-type, it would be things like `text/html`, `text/xml`, or `image/gif`.

The purpose here is to specify what type of data is being transmitted.

For header field definitions, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.

For the different media types, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type.

Also see the [NSURLRequest reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for specifics of that class.